# Unable to add a node in a linked list

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I tried to modify the code a few times but was unable to find the mistake in the code. My program is running but I have a hard time adding the node to the correct position.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data;
   struct Node *next;
}*HEAD=NULL;

void create(int a[],int n)
{
    struct Node *p;
    cout<<"Enter the number of elements of LL you want to display "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            HEAD=new Node;
            p=HEAD;
            p->data=a[0];
        }
        else
        {
            p->next=new Node;
            p=p->next;
            p->data=a[i];
        }
        
        
          p->next=NULL;
    }
 
}   
 void insertion(struct Node *p,int pos,int x)
{
    struct Node *t;
    int i,n;
    if(pos<0||pos>n)
    cout<<"Invalid position "<<endl;
    t=new Node;
     t->data=x;
    // t->next==NULL;
     if(pos==0)
     {
         t->next=HEAD;
         HEAD=t;
     }
     
    else
    for(i=0;i<pos-1;i++)
    {
        p=p->next;
        t->next=p->next;
        p->next=t;
    }
    
}
void display(struct Node *HEAD)
{   
    struct Node *p;
    p=HEAD;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<p->data;
        p=p->next;
        
    }
}
int main()
{
    struct Node *temp;
    int n;
    cout<<"enter the value of n "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];
    cout<<"Array elements are "<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    create(a,n);
   insertion(HEAD,1,15);
    display(HEAD);
}
```

Comment: First of all, please test early and test often. Don't write large parts of code without building (with extra warnings enable and that you treat as errors) and testing. That makes it much easier to understand when and where problems appear, and to *debug* the code (for example by using a debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values). And another tip when debugging: Use a pencil and paper to visualize the structures, nodes and links you have. Draw nodes as squares and links as arrows, erase and redraw arrows when you operate on them.

Comment: FYI, in C++ you don't need the keyword `struct` when declaring variables or parameters.

Comment: @Rohan Shahi This code snippet     int i,n;
    if(pos<0||pos>n) does not make a sense because the variable n is not initialized.

Comment: No need for the `if` case in the `for` loop in `create`. Do the work outside the loop and start the loop at `i = 1`.

Comment: @Rohan Shahi Also it is a bad idea when functions depend on a global variable as in your case on the global variable HEAD.

Comment: Why do you ask for the input of `n` in `create`, when it is already provided as argument, and was already input in the main program?

Comment: A warning: With a linked list it's really easy for a mistake at one end of the program to result in a visible error at the other end. This makes Some programmer dude's comment about write testing early and testing often absolutely vital. Also draw pictures to help yourself visualize what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

- In `insertion` you should move the following statements out of the loop, since they should only happen *once*, but also once when the loop does not iterate at all. This is the reason why you don't see a node added when you pass a position of 1:

  ```
  t->next = p->next;
  p->next = t;
  ```
- `if(pos<0||pos>n)` is not reliable as `n` is not initialised. You should not need `n` at all. You can make the second test while walking through the list and bumping into the end of the list before reaching the desired position.
- Don't ask for input of `n` in `create` as you already got this input in the main program.
- Your `display` function sticks all output together so that you cannot really see which  is which. You should separate values with a separator like a space.
- Don't use a global variable for your list. It is bad practice and will not allow you to use these functions for when you have more than one list.
- Don't name that variable with all capitals. That is commonly reserved for constants.
- In C++ use `nullptr` and not `NULL` when assigning/comparing node pointers.
- When you find the position is out of range, you should exit the function.
- As `head` will not be a global variable, let `create` return it, and pass it by reference to `insertion`.
- Take note of [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include<iostream>

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

// Let function return the new linked list
Node *create(int a[], int n) {
    Node *head = nullptr; // local variable & not CAPS
    Node *p;
    if (n == 0)
        return nullptr;
    // No input should be asked here
    head = new Node;
    p = head;
    p->data = a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        p->next = new Node;
        p = p->next;
        p->data = a[i];
    }
    p->next = nullptr;
    return head;
}

void insertion(Node **head, int pos, int x) {
    if (pos < 0) {
        std::cout << "Invalid position " << std::endl;
        return; // Should quit!
    }
    Node *t = new Node;
    t->data = x;
    if (pos == 0) {
        t->next = *head;
        *head = t;
    } else {
        Node *p = *head;
        for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++) {
            p = p->next;
            // Without n you can test out of range here:
            if (p == nullptr) {
                std::cout << "Invalid position" << std::endl;
                delete t;
                return;
            }
        }
        // The following should happen outside the loop
        t->next = p->next;
        p->next = t;
    }
}

void display(Node *head) {   
    Node *p = head;
    while (p != nullptr) {
        std::cout << p->data << " "; // separate with space
        p = p->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl; // Newline
}

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cout << "Enter the value of n " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> n;

    int a[n];
    std::cout << "Array elements are " << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin >> a[i];
    }
    // Define head as local variable - no CAPS
    Node *head = create(a,n);
    display(head);
    insertion(&head, 1, 15);
    display(head);
}
```